# Angularjs Filtering results with multiple parameters

Tags: angularjs

What i'm trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/, i'm still fairly new to angularjs an sometimes i understand what the code does, but not how, taking a look to that example confuses me a bit.

I tried to make a custom  filter myself, in this code i try to pass an array of filters and push into the array out[], but it's not working.

```
App.filter('busqueda', function(){
         console.log($scope.busqueda);
  return function(input){
    var out = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(localidad){
       for (var i=0; i<$scope.busqueda.length; i++)
              out.push(busqueda[i]);
    })
    return out;
  }
})
```

that code doesn't seem to work, the only thing that does is leave my table blank. How i can fix this? what i'm missing?
code of chosen **select**:

```
  <select  ng-model="busqueda"  data-placeholder="Buscar..." multiple class="control-group chosen-select" chosen>
            <optgroup ng-repeat="pueblo in pueblos[0].estados | orderBy:'nombre'" label={{pueblo.nombre}}>
                    <option  value=""> </option>
                    <option  ng-repeat="localidad in pueblo.localidades | orderBy:'nombre'" value={{localidad.nombre}}>
                                  {{localidad.nombre}}</option>
            </optgroup>
</select>
```

the code of the filter on the table:

```
<tr  ng-repeat="pueblo in pueblos[0].estados | filter:busqueda | orderBy:'nombre' ">
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: please make a basic fiddle of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @mudasserajaz there is an example fiddle, not mine though, look what the select does, it filters the employees depending the company you select, you can select 2 or more of the companies

Comment: Please go through how to create custom filter, because you are doing it and  using it all wrong. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: @mudasserajaz no offense, but that guide it's not even that extensive or helpful